# Unable to load static file in django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

Here the relevant configuration for settings.py:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'marcador'
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#STATICFILES_DIR = (
#    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
#)

STATIC_ROOT = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))
```

In  project urls.py;

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('marcador.urls')),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', 
        {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='mysite_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',
        {'next_page': reverse_lazy('marcador_bookmark_list')}, 
        name='mysite_logout'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

in marcador app urls.py;

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$', 'marcador.views.bookmark_user',
        name='marcador_bookmark_user'),
    url(r'^$', 'marcador.views.bookmark_list', name='marcador_bookmark_list'),
]
```

in templates/base.html (extract);

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Marcador - {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{% static 'apple-touch-icon.png' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">

    <script src="{% static 'js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js' %}"></script>
</head>
```

Here my directory structure (project called marca and application is called marcador);

```
+-- marca
+-- marcador
|   +-- migrations
|   +-- templates
|       +-- marcador
+-- static
|   +-- admin
|   |   +-- css
|   |   +-- img
|   |   |   +-- gis
|   |   +-- js
|   |       +-- admin
|   +-- css
|   +-- img
|   +-- js
|       +-- vendor
+-- templates
```

Here a printout of the variable;

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import settings
>>> print settings.BASE_DIR
/home/fabrice/Documents/Programing/django/marca
>>> print settings.PROJ_DIR
/home/fabrice/Documents/Programing/django/marca/marca
>>> print settings.STATIC_URL
/static/
>>> print settings.STATICFILES_DIR
('/home/fabrice/Documents/Programing/django/marca/marca/static',)
>>> print settings.STATIC_ROOT
/home/fabrice/Documents/Programing/django/marca/static
>>>
```

Content the page is diaplayed correctly but bootstap is not loading because the server return the 404 errors;

```
[20/Sep/2015 16:09:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4822
[20/Sep/2015 16:09:54] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1676
[20/Sep/2015 16:09:54] "GET /static/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1694
[20/Sep/2015 16:09:54] "GET /static/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1751
[20/Sep/2015 16:09:54] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1649
[20/Sep/2015 16:09:54] "GET /static/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1691
[20/Sep/2015 16:09:54] "GET /static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1643
[20/Sep/2015 16:09:54] "GET /static/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1691
[20/Sep/2015 16:09:54] "GET /static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1643
```

I have read a few posts on the same issue but still can't get it working when I print the BASE_DIR variable I can see that the path is correct.

The only way I can get this working correctly is when I copy the bootstrap static files in;

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/css/
```

I just don't get it and spent quite some tim on it already.

Any suggestion?

for information I am doing this tutorial http://django-marcador.keimlink.de/en/

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Django documentation. There is a specific page about managing static files:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

During development your project urls.py should be:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('marcador.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

But in production, a common practice is to use you http server to handle your static files. The answer for a production configuration is to broad since it will depends on your stack.

Comment: set your STATIC_ROOT to be os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') and probably remove the setting STATICFILES_DIR

Comment: Still the same, no bootstrap, I must be doing something wrong

Comment: Have you tried to put move your static folder to your marcador app folder?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too late to answer but I found that if I use STATICFILES_DIRS like below and comment STATIC_ROOT, it works correctly

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `STATICFILES_DIR` contains a wrong value. You use `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')`.

Citing the [documentation for join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

> If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown
>   away and joining continues from the absolute path component.

Please have a look at the following code example:

```
>>> os.path.join('/a', 'b', '/c', 'd')
'/c/d'
```

Solution: remove the leading slash in `'/static'`: `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')`

Comment: Sorry Matthias there was a typo in my file, I have  tried many things and forgot to remove the "/"

Answer (score 0):

Let's see...
When you create a new project marca, you get a subfolder marca that contains your settings.py, wsgi.py etc. Usually, I create a static folder here for my non-app specific static files. I can then have a settings.py PROJ_DIR to target that e.g.

```
PROJ_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Now I have a PROJ_DIR pointing at my subfolder marca in addition to BASE_DIR. Now to more settings.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' #pretty much ok
STATICFILES_DIR = (
    os.path.join(PROJ_DIR, 'static'), #additional location of static files
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Files in STATIC_ROOT will be served at STATIC_URL (/static/ in your case), usually by a separate static file server like nginx. It should be empty initially. To get your files into STATIC_ROOT, run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

which will look in your app static folders and all paths in STATICFILES_DIR and create a directory structure ready to be served.

In your template, base.html, you'll need to add

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

I expect you'll get an error if you don't.
Basically, I'm proposing this new structure to you.

```
manage.py
+-- static (your STATIC_ROOT is currently pointing here. empty initially but check after running collectstatic
+-- marca
    settings.py
    wsgi.py
    urls.py
    +-- static
    |   +-- css
    |   +-- img
    |   +-- gis
    |   +-- js
    +-- templates
+-- marcador
|   +-- migrations
|   +-- templates
|       +-- marcador
```

Comment: Done as requested but still same issue, also note the output from collectstatic "0 static files copied to '/home/fabrice/Documents/Programing/django/marca/static', 62 unmodified."  Also as metioned only when I copy file in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/ it work as expected

Comment: Do you have Debug=False? You may want to set it to True while using the development server. 0 copied because you already have those files in there, you may just delete and run collectstatic again.

Comment: debug is set to true, I have removed the files and run collect static again but still no luck. Also collecstatic created a folder admin inside the folder static. I still can't figure out what is wrong

Comment: I changed STATIC_ROOT, it is not a tuple. I must have done copy and paste from your original code. This may just be the problem you had.

Comment: ok, the change to STATIC_ROOT does not really have much effect though. Is admin the only folder inside static? if that's the case, it can't find the other files in STATICFILES_DIR i.e. os.path.join(PROJ_DIR, 'static') where you should have your bootstrap files and other static files that are not app specific.

Comment: Right now I have no admin folder in there but I did before. I have updated my original post with a print out of the variables from settings.py